# Doctrine2 empty parameter on queryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying to check whether an user email is set or not. I am able to get the ones that are set to NULL but I am missing on the ones that have an empty string as the value. Here is my attempt:

```
$user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('(u.email IS NULL OR u.email = :empty)')
        ->setParameter('empty', "''")
        ->getQuery()->getResult()
;
```

I have no problem getting the NULL emails but I fail to get the empty string emails. Is there any way to accomplish this or is it not supported in DQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (EDIT #2):

```
$user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.email = NULL')
        ->orWhere('u.email = \'\'')
        ->getQuery()->getResult()
;
```

Does that work?

Comment: It throws an exception

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: Error: Expected Literal, got '"'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape the quotes, and plus I just realized you can use `"` in SQL, so I made it single quote (like your answer).

Comment: Seems about right. I didn't show it in the piece of code I wrote, but the reason I put the OR clause inside the where is because I had issues before mixing OR and AND in different where clauses. For example if you want the logic to be: x AND (y OR z) you need to do it my way. But for the case I asked here, your approach is correct

Answer (score 0):

Worths mention that the [Expr Helper from QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class) provides a function for that:

```
// Example - $qb->expr()->isNull('u.id') => u.id IS NULL
public function isNull($x); // Returns string
```

So for your case you can do something like:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

$qb
   ->where(
       $qb->expr()->orX(
           $qb->expr()->isNull('u.email'),
           $qb->expr()->eq('u.email', ':empty'),
       )
   )
   ->setParameter('empty', '""');

$users = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```